# Publishing Solution to multiple environments

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, msbuild

I have a aplication MVC and use msbuild to compile and publish the application in three different servers.

I´ve created a .bat file with the commands to call msbuild and it´s work fine.

```
call server_1.bat
call server_2.bat
call server_3.bat
```

For any file, i call the msbuild to build my solution and marked the params to deploy.
like this

```
msbuild.exe "C:\Source\GestaoEscolar\solution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishProfile=profileServer1 /p:Password="pwdServer1"

msbuild.exe "C:\Source\GestaoEscolar\solution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishProfile=profileServer2 /p:Password="pwdServer2"

msbuild.exe "C:\Source\GestaoEscolar\solution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishProfile=profileServer3 /p:Password="pwdServer3"
```

Finally my question.
In this cenario, msbuild is called three times and build the application three times, and publish in respect server.
I want build solution only one time and publish all server after. Is possible?

tks!

Comment: It does not build three times, as MSBuild should be smart enough to detect no change and skip the last two builds.

Comment: Yes, it build three times, because i´ve call her three times. Maybe the question is confused but what i want make is call the msbuild one time and set parameters of three servers.